# After deploying a fully functional Aura Component Bundle to some other environment, it always throws error 'Cannot read property __ of undefined'

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I have a Aura component bundle and its Apex controller. I deploy the same to some other environment. It gives this component error 'Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property '***' of undefined]
Callback failed: apex://Controller/ACTION$***'

Then it starts working on its own after some time. What could be the reason for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very difficult to answer your question without some source code posted. However, I can make some guesses at where you could look, based on the error text. Since the error is stated as being in an ACTION and a callback, this suggests that you are using a callback somewhere in your component's controller. This is commonly used to communicate with the Apex Controller class. So I would start by looking there.

Cannot read property '' of undefined is your next clue. The "undefined" is probably a JavaScript variable that is not being properly set in your callback. This could be because of scoping issues, or it could be a problem with a custom namespace if you have a different namespace on the environment from the one you developed on.